# Can the red dots disappear when a question is looked at/updated?

Tags: feature-request

There seem to be red dots appearing on questions:

[image: red dots right next to the title on questions on the left side]

If you hover over them they say "This question has new activity". The only problem I have with it is that it doesn't update unless you refresh the page AFAICT, which is a bit annoying. I don't know if this is actually feasible to implement, but I think it would be a good improvement.

Comment: How dare you not visit all the six hundred thousand questions? :p

Comment: @BhargavRao Sorry, I only have time for 599 999 of them.

Comment: I can't reproduce the dots (FF 68, Win10). Could it be the dark theme?

Comment: @Zoe It's probably a A/B test or however it's called. I also see them only occasionally. Right now I don't.

Comment: Yeah, a very buggy test. There was a red dot next to one of my filters just now, but there's none on the list. Guessing this is a new feature in that case. Makes it hard to verify though

Comment: I got some dots, refreshing outright removes them, so I can't get a stable repro. The dots do exist though

Comment: Is that a custom filter? The dots are built-in to Teams but the traffic on a Team is much lower. I'm not aware of moving them to the full site.

Comment: @Catija Yes it's a custom filter but I'm not using Teams at all.

Comment: Ah, sounds like we pushed some updates to the custom filters last night and this is intentional so unrelated to Teams. Thanks for the feedback, we'll look into how we can improve. :D

Comment: @Catija Yes, this happened today ona it shows up if you choose a filter. In fact, if you choose a filter (as in the screenshot) and then click on **Newest** (essentially, the same as the filter), then the filter on the left side gets highlighted saying there are new items, even though you *see them*. But the questions on the list don't have the red dot. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/B1B3IYT.png)